# Passing variable to a controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hello I am displaying data in the view but each time that i display i want to store the Student_id in a variable the pass that variable to a controller but it is giving me errors

```
foreach($results as $row)
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    echo '<a href="http://localhost/amref/mama/get_student?var1=<?php echo $row->student_id;?>" '.'<tr><td>'.$row->student_fname.' '.$row->student_lname.'</td><td>'.$row->gender.'</td><td>'. $row->res_district.' , '.$row->res_region.'</td><td>'.$row->collage_name.'</td><td>'.$row->course_name.'</td></tr>'.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: you are sending the result from database as STD object or array?Please give more more code to elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect and I am pretty sure you want that anchor tag nested inside a `<td>` element, maybe like this:

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="http://localhost/amref/mama/get_student?var1='.$row->student_id.'">'.$row->student_fname.' '.$row->student_lname.'</a></td><td>'.$row->gender.'</td><td>'. $row->res_district.' , '.$row->res_region.'</td><td>'.$row->collage_name.'</td><td>'.$row->course_name.'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Thanks alot Mr DAvid fox